# Why I'm getting different speed results with this script and speedtest website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanted to have something locally that I can use to measure my internet speed, instead of always going to [http://www.speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/). So I found [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Check-Internet-Connection-Download-Speed-using-C-and-VBNet-in-ASPNet.aspx) script summarized bellow:

```
int jQueryFileSize = 261; //Size of File in KB.
WebClient client = new WebClient();
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
client.DownloadFile("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js", Server.MapPath("~/jQuery.js"));
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
speeds[i] = Math.Round((jQueryFileSize / (endTime - startTime).TotalSeconds));
```

With the script I get average 2800 - 3600 KB/s BUT when I go to the speedtest website I get 73 - 74 Mbps (And that's what I'm paying for, and I get closer to that in my torrent downloads). Obviously It would be hard for 6 lines of code to be able to work as good as an entire business made solely for this purpose, but still it shouldn't be impossible for me to be able to get my internet speed locally. I'm ruining the script on a localhost .net website.

So why is this script not working properly ?
**Is it because the file is not big enough and the download happens so fast there is no time to achieve  the actual speeds my internet is capable of ?** (Similarly to torrent downloads, where I start off slowly and then go to 5-7Mbps

Comment: 1) use Stopwatch class instead of DateTime. 2) To avoid disk speed to effect your measurement, download to memory 3) Use a larger file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpeedTest checks large (multi-megabyte) files because a small file (like a minified, gzipped jQuery) won't reflect your full speed due to stuff like HTTPS negotiation, TCP overhead, etc.

Comment: Oh yeah, bumping the file size to 10 megs brings more favourable results
1x5.5 , 2x6.6 and 7x 8.7-.9 MB per second

Answer (score 2):

Two things. First it looks like you're getting 22.4 - 28 Mbps (instead of MBps) with your test, which isn't vastly far from your 73/74 from Speedtest.Net (assuming that's what you're using).

Second of all, the file you're downloading is fairly small (less than 0.3 MB), and there's overhead for any download request (creating the request and sending out the request). Try a larger file, and I imagine your calculation will be closer.

Also you might adjust your code to be Mbps instead of MBps.